# Kodi Touchscreen Gesture missing configuration

Tags: gesture, touchscreen, kodi

Can i ask is there anyway to configure the kodi mediaplayer setting for the touch screen gesture? eg. double tap to pause/resume video.

devon

Answer (score 0):

A touchscreen.xml exists in kodi.
There you can modify the default gestures.

Check http://kodi.wiki/view/touch_controls for further information.